# What is maximum length of atom strings in wide characters, 255 or 127?

Tags: c++, winapi

[Atom tables reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649053%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#_win32_String_Atoms) says it is 255 ***bytes***, so it gives me 127 characters, but in my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20868684/what-are-real-minimum-version-requirements-for-attachconsole) I've learned what MSDN isnt always accurate. Unfortunately, in this case there is no authoritative definion in PSDK headers.
I've also checked WINE sources, they use 255 characters:

```
#define MAX_ATOM_LEN 255
...
WCHAR buffer[MAX_ATOM_LEN];
```

Comment: You failed to understand the answer to your previous question: The MSDN **is** accurate. You are confusing *can be made to work* and *is a supported scenario*. The MSDN specifies the latter. I'm not suggesting, that the MSDN is **always** correct. However, the answers to your previous question do not suggest inaccuracies.

Comment: If you're going to accept an answer, it should be @Retired Ninja's, imo.

Comment: @IInspectable, yes, I do not see how (possible buggy) documentation (provided as-is) obliges MS with `...`. My previous Q body demonstrates clearly inaccurate version is documentation.

Comment: Your previous question merely demonstrates, that you are reading something into the documentation that isn't there. The documentation is accurate. Important detail: *"Minimum **supported** client"*. It does **not** say *"Will not compile for previous versions"*.

Comment: @IInspectable, no. You are ignoring *remarks* section. It **does** contradict *requirements* section. More than enough to call that version inaccurate.

Comment: The *Remarks* section merely gives instructions for making `AttachConsole` available to a program. It is not meant to be interpreted as the minimum requirement. The minimum requirements are listed in the *Requirements* sections. The documentation - even the **outdated** one you are referencing - is accurate.

Answer (score 3):

Seems easy enough to test, on my machine, 255 succeeds and 256 fails with `ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER`.  Of course you could just use a shorter string.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    const std::wstring s1(255, L'A');
    const std::wstring s2(256, L'A');
    ATOM a = AddAtomW(s1.c_str());
    if(!a || FindAtomW(s1.c_str()) != a)
    {
        std::cerr << "AddAtom/FindAtom @ len 255 failed - " << GetLastError() << "\n";
    }
    DeleteAtom(a);
    a = AddAtomW(s2.c_str());
    if(!a || FindAtomW(s2.c_str()) != a)
    {
        std::cerr << "AddAtom/FindAtom @ len 256 failed - " << GetLastError() << "\n";
    }
    DeleteAtom(a);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I ran similar testcases on atom-alike functions RegisterClass/RegisterWindowMessage/RegisterClipboardFormat. All of the PASS with 255 widechars and FAIL with 256. Windows 7. Please refine your Windows version.

Comment: -1 You cannot write a test case to deduce contractual rules. Those rules can only be discovered by reading the documentation.

Comment: @IInspectable: I can point you to lots of examples of the documentation being wrong. MSDN is not infallible.

Comment: I will note additionally that the documentation for `RegisterClass` (which uses ATOMs internally) specifically says "The maximum length for lpszClassName is 256.". Bytes? Characters? It doesn't say. And 256 is wrong anyway since as the answer shows, 256 will actually fail - it should say 255. The documentation is clearly wrong.

Comment: @JonathanPotter: That's incorrect logic: Windows version Foo can assume things about the internals Windows version Foo, but that doesn't mean you can rely on those same internals.

Answer (score 1):

The maximum length indeed is 127 characters, per the documentation. Any implementation may use a higher value for internal reasons, because that does not affect any correct program.

The other answer (from RetiredNinja) assumes that an implementation *must* give an error for an invalid parameter. That's not how Windows works.

Comment: MSDN documentation is not infallible. It seems far more likely to me that the limit is 255 characters rather than bytes.

Comment: @Jonathan `ATOM`s are ancient. It seems far more likely that the max. size is actually specified in bytes. After all, they were invented in a time, when `1 character == 1 byte` was always true.

Comment: @IInspectable And then porting working code to UNICODE breaks... MS did the right thing, it's 255 "characters"

Comment: @manuell You're getting things equally wrong as Retired Ninja: The documentation specifies the supported range. Anything outside the supported range (i.e. > 127 Unicode characters) is not a supported use case, and the behavior is unspecified. Appearing to succeed is a valid form of unspecified behavior. MSalters got things right.

Comment: @IInspectable I see your point. But I think MSDN (on that subject) is just not up to date, especially if 255 wchar_t is ok, and 256 not ok. Would be interesting to test AddAtomW with 2 big strings differing only by the last wide char...

Comment: @IInspectable: manuell is right. A 255 character atom would work (and is contractually supported) in an ANSI build, but fail in a Unicode build? No chance.

Comment: @Jonathan It breaks for a Unicode build already, since you have it declared as `char wndcls = "blah";`. A C compiler will produce code, that fails at runtime, since you're reinterpreting ANSI as Unicode. A C++ compiler will simply acknowledge that it cannot convert from `char*` to `wchar_t*`. For a Unicode build you have to modify code, and you're best advised to look up the documentation while doing so. Sorry, MSalters is still correct here: 255 bytes, as documented. If it works for 255 Unicode characters, good! If it fails at some point, don't ask for support.

Comment: I realize that the topic is really old, but I find it funny how @IInspectable tried to defend the documentation from some formal PoV, but didn't even consider that it simply can't be 127 even theoretically, given that atom names are e.g. case-insensitive. As such, they are not just bytes, but strings. And so, if they are stored as UTF-16 internally, then a limit of 127 16-bit characters would mean the same 127 characters for 8-byte strings, *or* if they are stored as 8-byte strings, then you can't easily give a "limit is N" for UTF-16-to-ACP, as it may be 1:5 or the like.

Comment: @MikeKaganski The question is about the **length** not the set of unique values that fit inside that range. That out of the way, do you have anything valuable to contribute?

Comment: @IInspectable: exactly. And the length definitely depends on the "set of unique values that fit inside that range", when you consider the string conversions from one format to the other, that must happen to store the value in the core.

Comment: Regarding "anything valuable" - well, if you insist: MS has this piece of documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ddeml/nf-ddeml-ddecreatestringhandlew. It tells: "The null-terminated string for which a handle is to be created. This string can be up to 255 characters. The reason for this limit is that DDEML string management functions are implemented using atoms."

And given that this is about wide-string function, this is the exact place where one piece of documentation contradicts another.

Comment: @MikeKaganski *"And the length definitely depends on the "set of unique values that fit inside that range""* - It's the other way around: The set of unique values has an upper bound that's dictated by the size. Regardless, this is about contractual guarantees, and the contract guarantees 127 characters. Everything else has been said before. If you care enough to know, re-read the comments you responded to. Make sure to take your time to digest the information.

Comment: Sigh. Let me then try to describe something to you, because it's exactly about "contractual guarantees". This question is about something which is used in inter-process protocols (DDE); and when the documentation states: "maximum is 255 bytes", it makes it impossible to communicate between processes using A-functions and processes using W-functions: because, as long as the *guarantee* is concerned, a proper programming is to provide 255-*byte* buffer to W-functions, and they can't obtain atoms  coming from A-functions that passed 200+ *characters* there.