# Delphi and Python - A few short queries

Tags: python, list, delphi, directory

Okay, first question; should be reasonably simple to answer, but as a somewhat beginner programmer I'm unsure of the solution:

- Is there a way to display an entire filepath that's been extracted using SHGetSpecialFolderPath  - I'd like to create what is essentially a table that contains subdirectories of the folder I want and displays them like:

> C:\Folder\Folder2
>
> C:\Folder\Folder3
>
> C:\Folder\Folder4

So, the first query is how would I achieve that? (I'm not fussed about whether it's in console mode
or in a form, though I'd imagine using a ListBox in a form would be more appropriate?)

Secondly, I'd like to know if I could do the above with my %AppData% folder -

```
C:\Users\...\AppData\Skype
C:\Users\...\AppData\Firefox
```

- etcetera, is this possible? And if so, how?

Thirdly, and finally - I seem to recall I -would- be able to do this sort of thing easily in Python, so is it viable at all to use Delphi coding to call a Python script (The software I'm using normally uses Delphi scripts, so I'm having to teach it to myself as I use it (sort-of dropping myself at the deep end, I know) - but could I write some kind of procedure in Delphi, for example by modifying the startup script for the software, and get it to call a script made in Python, or are they totally incompatible?

Again, if it's possible, I'd appreciate being told how (because I've no clue!)

Thanks for reading (and contributing, if you do!)

Comment: Adding Python to the mix won't help. That will just make life more complex. Nothing wrong with Python, but just no need to mix them. You can do this all from Delphi. However, I'm not really clear on what your problem is. `SHGetSpecialFolderPath` already returns a complete path.

Comment: In all honesty I may just be using it wrong - I don't really understand how it works! 

Writeln(SHGetSpecialFolderPath(CSIDL_APPDATA, 'C', 1 , FALSE));

is what's being inputted, because from what I understood, the first part is the identity, second part is the location, third part.. I don't know, and the last part is just a boolean as to whether to create the file if it doesn't exist already? 

Because.. when I run this, I just get a message saying "FALSE" - I'm clearly doing it wrong, I'm just not sure what I need to change!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing to be gained from shelling out to Python here. Delphi can do all you need easily enough, you just have to work out how to make the magic incantations.

It looks like you are just calling `SHGetSpecialFolderPath` incorrectly. Here is how I do it:

```
type
  TWin32PathBuffer = array [0..Windows.MAX_PATH-1] of char;

function GetSpecialFolderPath(const CSIDL: Integer): string;
var
  Buffer: TWin32PathBuffer;
begin
  Win32Check(SHGetSpecialFolderPath(0, @Buffer[0], CSIDL, False));
  Result := Buffer;
end;
```

The final part of the jigsaw is how to enumerate sub-directories. In modern Delphi you can use `TDirectory.GetDirectories` from the `IOUtils` unit. If you don't have a modern Delphi then you have to call `FindFirst`, `FindNext` etc. There are at least a gazillion examples of this code to be found on the web. This one appears to do what you need: http://delphi.about.com/od/delphitips2008/qt/subdirectories.htm

Comment: I get an "undeclared identifier: Windows" if I try and run it that way - What do I need to be using to get that fixed?

Nevermind, added Windows to Uses and it fixed that, next error is:

"Symbol Win32Check is specific to a platform". Any ideas?

Comment: Either use `Windows`, or change `Windows` to `Winapi.Windows`. That's an incredibly basic question. No offence, but perhaps you need to brush up on the basics before attempting this.

Comment: Oh, undoubtably I do, I haven't done anything to do with this for now.. four years? I think. I still remember a few bits and pieces but a lot is gone! Still, I figured that last bit out just as you posted it. Now Win32Check is specific to a platform and "undeclared identifier: application" are the only issues it seems to have.

Comment: Well, the fact that `Win32Check` is specific to a platform is nothing to worry about. After all, you are calling `SHGetSpecialFolderPath` aren't you. If you don't want to pass a handle, for instance you have a console app, pass `0` instead of `Application.Handle`.

Comment: @David, wait, have you checked the reference for the [`SHGetSpecialFolderPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762204(v=vs.85).aspx) ? Not only that the *"SHGetSpecialFolderPath is not supported."* (end of client support Windows 2000 Professional) but the `hwndOwner` parameter is marked as *"Reserved"*. Are you sure this function is the right choice ? Well, my guess is that it is exported and internally calls `ShGetFolderPath` function (which in turn internally *links* to `SHGetKnownFolderPath` on Vista above).

Comment: @TLama I don't really know what *End of client support* means. It's not as if the function doesn't work. I still call it because of the pain involved with having to support XP still.

Comment: @TLama, it looks like yet another MSDN content glitch. Anyway, I've learned from `[winapi]` guys what MS occasionally *may* throw away from reference anything not supported as whole product in whole, so historical info on the specific functions *may* remain in PSDK headers only. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20868684/what-are-real-minimum-version-requirements-for-attachconsole